# How to navigate to the method declaration of a Ruby on Rails method in Sublime Text?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sublimetext2, keyboard-shortcuts, ctags

I am looking for a functionality for easy navigation of source code.

**Here is my problem to be specific:**

I use Sublime Text, and I often tend to read the method definition of a lot
of methods before implementing them, but for that, I need to go to the
source code on GitHub and search for that exact location where the method
is defined

**What I am looking for:**

I am looking for a functionality wherein, when I double click on a method, 
it should open the definition of the method at the same place, preferably
in a new tab.

### Example:

In Rails, clicking on the method `before_filter` should
open the method definition of `before_filter`.

This is similar to:

> ⌘ + mouse-click

functionality in [RubyMine](http://rubymine.com). More information [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/help/navigating-to-declaration-or-type-declaration-of-a-symbol.html).

I have referred to articles for CTags which do not seem to help.

Comment: To clarify, you want Sublime to open up github source code and display the method definition for `before_filter`?

Comment: What I want is: not to open GitHub source in the browser, but in some way, locate the source code in the local computer, and show the corresponding method definition from there.

Answer (score 5):

In **Sublime Text 3**,

There are two way to do it.

1. Right click on method or text and you will see "Goto Defination"

Or

2. Shortcut key is <kbd>F12</kbd>

Comment: I am talking about a situation wherein a method is not defined in the same project you are working in.

Comment: might also need to enable indexing `"index_files": true,` in settings